# Visualforce Get Contact from Opportunity ID

Tags: visualforce

newbie here... Im wanting to do a lookup on the OpptyId, from there grab the ContactID and do another lookup to the Contact. Right now Im getting "Attempt to de-reference a null object" Im not really sure what Im doing but I feel like it has to do with how the object is defined/accessed from within the controlled. My code is below, any help or reading would be appreciated. thanks!

```
public class ScholarshipSummary {
    
    Opportunity opportunity{set;get;}
    Contact contact{set;get;}
    
    public Opportunity getOpportunity() {
        if (opportunity == null){                      
        opportunity = [select First_Name__c,Last_Name__c,Expected_Start_Date__c,ContactId from Opportunity where 
                       id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') AND RecordTypeId ='0124P000000BWnXQAW'];
        }
        return opportunity;

    }
 
    public Contact getContact() {
        if (contact == null){                      
        contact = [select Name,Text_First_Name__c,MailingStreet,MailingCity,MailingState,MailingPostalCode from Contact where 
                   id = :opportunity.ContactId];
        }
        return contact;
    
    }
    

    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would surmise your issue is that you have defined two getters for each of {Opportunity, Contact} - you only need one

This is the pattern I use:

```
public Opportunity opportunity {
  get {
    if (opportunity == null){                      
    opportunity = [select First_Name__c,Last_Name__c,Expected_Start_Date__c,ContactId from Opportunity where 
                   id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') AND RecordTypeId ='0124P000000BWnXQAW'];
    }
    return opportunity;

  } set;
}
```

and same for Contact; you can remove the methods getOpportunity, getContact as they are duplicative

As an aside, don't use RecordTypeId strings - use `Recordtype.DeveloperName = 'myRecordTypeDevName'`

Comment: thanks so much, that was it and took your advice on recordtype as well. thanks again!